# How to convert DWG to DXF from a PHP script?

Tags: php, file, web, cad, dwg

I'm making a website for a customer where users can upload their CAD files to calculate a quote. Since DXF file format is the same of the DWG, I have choosen the DXF's one because it's ASCII. The script is ready, but my customer wants also to upload DWG on the website. Now, I have found plenty of converters, but the job must be done on the website automatically when an user uploads his own files. What I'm trying to ask is: there is some script, some libraries (js, php or python) or algorithm to convert DWG files to DXF?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: lmgtfy: http://anydwg.com/dwg-dxf/

Comment: Google failed you @Thomas.  That program is a standalone windows program, not a back end web program.  I would imagine if he had a dedicated windows server he could install the program on it and use the command line version of the Pro version of the program.  But if ReDevilGames is using PHP, he would likely have a UNIX/Linix server.

Comment: @Jeff so it took one year to dig that?

Comment: @Thomas it did not take a year of dig'n.  I read this post in January (2016) doing some research on DXF files.  I replied at that time.  I am in the process of writing PHP programs to create and read DXF files.

Comment: @Jeff did you succeed with PHP-DWG reader?